# cannot delete linux image due to dependencies

Tags: grub2, delete

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I stil have Windows on my machine as well. After installing Ubuntu I noticed I had two Linux images on my machine in GRUB. One of them causes failure while booting, the second one does not. (The funny thing is that it is the more recent one that is not working, 3.13)

So I would like to delete the first one. I have been reading some help questions and tried some suggestions but it says I can't delete the images due to dependencies. How can I delete the non-working image?

Thank you in advance,

joost

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get purge [kernel version]` rather than simply `remove`?

Comment: If you use `sudo apt-cache rdepends linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic` (assuming you're fully updated) that will tell you what packages need the more recent kernel. Sadly I think because 3.13 is the current Trusty one you'll have to leave that installed and keep manually booting the older kernel until the new one is fixed. Report a bug (saying that it's 3.13 that's broken) with `ubuntu-bug linux`

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get dist-upgrade
 apt-get autoremove
 apt-get clean
 UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
 apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
 NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
 ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
 METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
 UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
 apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
```